# Bash script: regexp reading numerical parameters from text file

Tags: bash, file, parsing, shell

Greetings!

I have a text file with parameter set as follows:

---

NameOfParameter Value1 Value2 Value3 ...
...

---

I want to find needed parameter by its **NameOfParameter** using regexp pattern and return a selected **Value** to my Bash script.
I tried to do this with grep, but it returns a whole line instead of **Value**.

Could you help me to find as approach please?

Comment: Do you need to return all 3 values? only 1?

Comment: By what criterion do you select the selected value?  Is the parameter name a column name or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

It was not clear if you want all the values together or only one specific one. In either case, use the power of `cut` command to cut the columns you want from a file (`-f 2-` will cut columns 2 and on (so everything except parameter name; `-d " "` will ensure that the columns are considered to be space-separated as opposed to default tab-separated)

```
egrep '^NameOfParameter ' your_file | cut -f 2- -d " "
```

Answer (score 0):

Bash:

```
values=($(grep '^NameofParameter '))
echo ${values[0]}    # NameofParameter 
echo ${values[1]}    # Value1
echo ${values[2]}    # Value2
# etc.

for value in ${values[@:1]}    # iterate over values, skipping NameofParameter
do
    echo "$value"
done
```

Comment: Is there any opportunity to use this method for data with non-space delimiters: comma, dot, tab, etc.?

Comment: @Andrey: Set IFS to the delimiter: `saveIFS=$IFS; IFS=','; values=($(grep '^NameofParameter ')); IFS=$saveIFS; ...`